# Integrating Azure Service Bus Topic and Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics

I created an **Azure Function** and selected **Azure Service Bus Topic** as the trigger in **Visual Studio 2019**. I also created a **Service Bus Topic** in my Azure account and have the **Primary Connection String** and **Primary Key**.

My questions are:

1. How can I integrate the **Azure Service Bus** with the **Azure Function** that I created? What attributes should be changed in the code generated?
2. How can I send a message to **Azure Service Bus** Topic locally on my machine? Is there any application like **SQL Management Studio** that can connect to my **Azure Service Bus** resource?

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("mytopic", "mysubscription", Connection = "ConnectionString")]string mySbMsg, ILogger log)
{
   log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the tree attributes, and add them to the local.settings.json:
You will have your Trigger like this:

```
[ServiceBusTrigger(
                topicName: "%MyServiceBus.Topic%",
                subscriptionName: "%MyServiceBus.Subscription%",
                Connection = "MyServiceBus.Connection")]
```

And your local.settings.json like this:

```
 {  
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "PriorityBoardingFare.Topic": "TestEvent",
    "PriorityBoardingFare.Subscription": "Appl1cation1",
    "PriorityBoardingFare.Connection": "Endpoint=sb://xxxxxxxxx.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=xxxxxxd;SharedAccessKey=adasdasdasdasdasdasd"    
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 21094
  }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#local-settings-file

To send or manage the service bus you have now available two options:

1. This is what we use at my work, its a community tool to manage the SB: https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer
2. And this is the microsoft's tool: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/explorer.

Comment: It worked locally after I changed the attribute settings like you suggested. I hosted the app in Azure now. I don't know where to look for the log which is written by the ```log.LogInformation``` call. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I use the Application Insights to do that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring?tabs=cmd, but if you dont want to enable it you can see the logs on the Kudu->DebugConsole->Powersell and there you will have a folder call "LogFiles".

Answer (score 0):

There is in ServiceBusTrigger 2 overloads:

```
public ServiceBusTriggerAttribute(string queueName);
public ServiceBusTriggerAttribute(string topicName, string subscriptionName);
```

You can choice.